# How does certain applications bypass UAC for a non-administrator user in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, uac, privileges, github-desktop

I created a new user account on Windows 10 whose type is "standard user" and in which the User Account Control (UAC) setting is set to "Always notify". To test the privileges, I download GitHub Desktop and it installed itself without asking any question whatsoever. There was no prompt for password from the administrator account, only a splash screen saying that "GitHub Desktop is being installed" and a window asking for GitHub credentials after that. The app was indeed successfully installed because it was listed in the "App & Features" list, but I don't see why Windows would allow it to happen.

What am I missing? And how do I make sure applications always ask for permission before being installed? For instance, if it was a misclick, GitHub Desktop would install itself anyway, without giving me a chance to correct my mistake or even cancel the process.

Comment: Does it install itself into the PATH, or the registry, or in sensitive folders such as `C:\Program Files`? If it doesn't do any of the above, it doesn't need admin permissions.

Comment: @harrymc It does not, and now it makes sense. So I guess that the lack of confirmation of intent is merely a lack of proper regard for the user. Would you write an answer?

Comment: “how do I make sure applications always ask for permission before being installed?” - Most applications don’t actually need elevated permissions to be installed.  There is a group policy that you can enable to prevent programs from being installed as a normal user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An application like an installer only needs administrator permissions
if it intends to add itself into the PATH, or modify the registry,
or modify sensitive and protected folders such as `C:\Program Files`.

An application that does not do any of the above,
doesn't need administrator permissions and will have no reason
to ask for them.